# Synchronization and result retrieval with ASIO coroutines and networking TS with C++20

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, asio

I am experimenting with asio stackless coroutines and newly introduced C++20 constructs for `co_return`, `co_await`.

I went through the examples and have a few questions based on my understanding and because I still see race condition related crashes :(

Example: (I am going to omit all exception handing for the sake of simplicity)

```cpp
awaitable<size_t> echo_request(tcp::socket& socket)
{
  using namespace boost::asio;
  using namespace std::literals;
  
  char data[3] = {};

  co_await async_write(socket, buffer("abc"sv), use_awaitable);
  size_t n = co_await async_read(socket, buffer(data, sizeof(data)), transfer_all(), use_awaitable);

  co_return n;
}


int main()
{

  // calling the coroutines

  using namespace boost::asio;

  auto ctx = io_context{};

  auto sockets = vector<tcp::socket>{};
  for(auto i{0}; i<20; ++i)
    sockets.push_back(make_connection(...));

  auto strand = make_strand(ctx);

  for(auto&& socket : sockets)
    co_spawn(strand, echo_request(), detached);

  auto th = std::thread([&]{ ctx.run(); });
  ctx.run();
  th.join();
}
```

I understand that `ctx.run()` will be executed as many times as there are current tasks. Because in the above example 20 times `co_spawn` is being called with 2 `co_wait` calls each, the sum of all `ctx.run()` results will be 40. However, here the `awaitable<size_t>` returns a result. How can this result be retrieved from the `main` function?

I saw one example where an `std::promise` has been used in a lambda function instead of `detached` awaitable:

```cpp
std::promise<size_t> p;

co_spawn(strand, echo_request(), [&p](auto&& err, auto&& value)
{
  if(err) p.set_exception(err);
  else p.set_value(value);
});
```

`std::promise` might internally use a mutex (and in fact it does use it). Is there any more lightweight alternative?

Finally, what would happen if any of the `echo_request` functions would modify non-atomic value (it might be a more complex structure like hash table, but here it's just an int increment to a global variable).

Example:

```cpp
int total_requests = 0;

awaitable<size_t> echo_request(tcp::socket socket)
{
  using namespace boost::asio;
  using namespace std::literals;
  
  char data[3] = {};

  co_await async_write(socket, buffer("abc"sv), use_awaitable);

  ++total_requests;  // THIS IS A RACE CONDITION

  size_t n = co_await async_read(socket, buffer(data, sizeof(data)), transfer_all(), use_awaitable);

  ++total_requests;  // ANOTHER RACE CONDITION

  co_return n;
}
```

My understanding that if asynchronous operations are executed within a `strand` they are linearized (without order guarantee). Basically, even running `io_context::run()` from multiple threads assures that there will be no concurrency between the awaitables executed within one strand? I was expecting that the following modification would fix the issue, but it did not.

Furthermore, only places marked with `co_await` are interruption points. So if multiple function instances running within the same strand outside the `co_await` there will be no interruption. Basically, the code fragment marked with `// THIS IS A RACE CONDITION` cannot end up executing by 2 threads concurrently and it's safe to increment the global variable. Is this correct?

If that is not so, would the below code fragment prevent the race condition?

```cpp
int total_requests = 0;

awaitable<size_t> echo_request(boost::asio::strand& strand, boost::asio::tcp::socket& socket)
{
  using namespace boost::asio;
  using namespace std::literals;
  
  char data[3] = {};

  co_await async_write(socket, buffer("abc"sv), use_awaitable);

  strand.execute([&] { ++total_reqeusts; });  // WOULD THAT PREVENT THE RACE CONDITION???

  size_t n = co_await async_read(socket, buffer(data, sizeof(data)), transfer_all(), use_awaitable);

  strand.execute([&] { ++total_requests; });

  co_return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.run` will run until all work on the io_context is complete.  So if you remove this line

```
auto th = std::thread([&]{ ctx.run(); });
```

You'll convert your application into a single threaded async application. Then you don't need to worry about strands etc.

As a single threaded app it's OK to sum requests or bytes to your global variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I would like to use the multi-threaded approach and want to understand why strands do no linearize the concurrency where they should.

Comment: Generally, I considered such a proposal before, but the app I am going to refactor now deals with at least 2 threads accessing a shared state. Thus I really want to understand, why strand is not linearizing the parallelism.